# how do i extract subtitles from a video using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried with several videos but I am encountering the same error as:
'**Output file #0 does not contain any stream**'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if soft sub

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i 1.mkv
```

.

```
    Input #0, matroska,webm, from '1.mkv':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : libebml v1.3.6 + libmatroska v1.4.9
        creation_time   : 2020-06-27T08:04:52.000000Z
      Duration: 01:02:06.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 662 kb/s
        

Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          BPS-eng         : 500501
          DURATION-eng    : 01:02:05.834000000
          NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 89420
          NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 233098262
          _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v31.0.0 ('Dolores In A Shoestand') 64-bit
          _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-06-27 08:04:52
          _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
        

Stream #0:1(eng): Subtitle: subrip
        Metadata:
          title           : English@BonsaiHD.Fun
          BPS-eng         : 25
          DURATION-eng    : 01:01:07.500000000
          NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 449
          NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 11798
          _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v31.0.0 ('Dolores In A Shoestand') 64-bit
          _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-06-27 08:04:52
          _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
        
Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip (default) (forced)
            Metadata:
              title           : English_Forced@@BonsaiHD.Fun
              BPS-eng         : 1
              DURATION-eng    : 00:57:12.917000000
              NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 21
              NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 448
              _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v31.0.0 ('Dolores In A Shoestand') 64-bit
              _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-06-27 08:04:52
              _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
            


Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: subrip
        Metadata:
          title           : English@BonsaiHD.Fun
          BPS-eng         : 36
          DURATION-eng    : 00:57:14.833000000
          NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 594
          NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 15793
          _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v31.0.0 ('Dolores In A Shoestand') 64-bit
          _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-06-27 08:04:52
          _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
        

Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          BPS-eng         : 160000
          DURATION-eng    : 01:02:06.368000000
          NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 116449
          NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 74527360
          _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v31.0.0 ('Dolores In A Shoestand') 64-bit
          _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-06-27 08:04:52
          _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
```

this video has 5 streams; 0:0 is video & 0:4 is audio & 0:1, 0:2, 0:3 are subtitles

to extract the sub in 0:1 stream in my file 1.mkv to subtitle1.ass or subtitle1.srt file

```
ffmpeg -v error -stats -i 1.mkv -vn -an -map 0:1 subtitle1.ass
```

Comment: I tried on the videos which i have its that only video and audio streams are found.Also I want to know where I can find such MKV container videos to extract subtitles?

Comment: then your video has a hard subtitles. nothing can be done in this case. if this is a movie or a series you can find subtitles at subscene.com \ opensubtitles.org

Answer (score -1):

STEP 1 : First list all the audio stream
STEP 2 : ffmpeg -i VIDEO.mkv, ffmpeg -i input.mkv
STEP 3 : Compile the command to extract the audio track